# Функция JS не определенна

Tags: javascript

Я пишу свой сайт, и тут вроде бы всё было нормально, но через какое-то время появилось это в консоли браузера:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Regs is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Что делать?

Код JS:

```
function Regs() {
  var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("mail").value;

  if (login.length < 3) {
    alert("В логине слишком мало букв! Должно быть не менее 4");
  } else if (password.length < 3) {
    alert("В пароле мало символов! Должно быть не менее 4");
  } else if (login.length > 15) {
    alert("В логине слишком много символов!");
  } else if (login.length > 3 && login.length < 15) {
    alert("Если вы залогинитесь, тогда всё получится :)");
    var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "functions.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email));
    NickName = login;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваша функция `Regs` находится внутри какой-то другой функции. Вынесите ее наружу, в глобальную область видимости или туда, где ее будет видно из `onclick` обработчика.

```html
<script>
function Regs() {
  console.log("Regs");
}
</script>

<input type="submit" onclick="Regs()" value="Click" />
```

Comment: Не получается , проверил все скобки и все нормально

Comment: @VIP300100 Хорошо. Где находится функция `Regs`?

Comment: она в тэге <script> только одна

Comment: @VIP300100 Хорошо. Где находится этот тег по отношению к элементу `input` с атрибутом `onclick`, до `input`-a или после ?

Comment: <head> ->  <script> -> <body (input)> то есть после

Comment: @VIP300100  то есть до?

Comment: Ой, извеняюсь , да , до, поставил после и то же самое

Comment: Ничего не получилось , но сейчас буду пытаться , спасибо !